# A Canonical Transformation that deletes one canonical coordinate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

I am self studying some classical mechanics, and came across a problem in Goldstein that has me stumped.  It is problem 1 in chapter 10.  It basically says "Given some conservative system show that a canonical transformation can be constructed such that the new Hamiltonian is dependent only on the new coordinates."  It wants this to be done by writing down some PDE whose solution is a generating function.  I can't get far on this...let's just work in one dimension for now.  The old coordinates $(q,p)$ will go to $(Q,P)$.  But we know,
$$K(Q)=H(q,p)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}  $$
$$\dot{Q}=0=\frac{\partial K}{\partial P}  $$
And a few other identities that are unchanged.  I have tried messing around with different types of generating functions, but I can't seem to get any kind of useful PDE written down.  The problem also says to not use a type 1 generating function for some reason.  I am having trouble seeing how we can simply eliminate one of the coordinates in general.  Can someone give a hint towards a solution? In particular your thought process on how you came towards something workable?

Comment: [Action-angle variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates) should be useful.

Comment: Can action angle type coordinates be defined when motion isn't bounded in phase space? @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: I dont think so, but maybe.